# Gatsby/Strapi with GraphQl Relational data will not populate on page

Tags: postgresql, graphql, relationship, gatsby, strapi

For some reason only part of this script is working. But the `new_students` query will not work.

```
import React from "react"
import styled from "styled-components"

import {  Link, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import ClassImg from 'gatsby-background-image'
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import "./class.scss"
```

Everything else except this part `<p>{classdesc.new_students.firstname}</p>`

```
const ClassName = styled.div`
  color: white;
`
const Section = styled.div`
  margin-top: 20px
`

export default function Class({ data }) {
  const classdesc = data.strapiClassList
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container className={`justify-content-md-center pt-5`}>
        <Row className={`justify-content-md-center`}>
          <Col className={`col-md-auto`}>
            <ClassImg
              Tag="section"
              className={`class-img`}
              fixed={classdesc.class_img.childImageSharp.fixed}
            >
              <ClassName className={`class-name text-center`}>{classdesc.classname}</ClassName>
            </ClassImg>
            <Section>
              <p>{classdesc.days}</p>
              <p>{classdesc.start} - {classdesc.end}</p>
              <p>{classdesc.class_desc}</p>
              <p>{classdesc.new_students.firstname}</p>
            </Section>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

GraphQL

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    strapiClassList(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      classname
      zoomurl
      days
      start
      end
      class_desc
      class_img {
        childImageSharp {
          fixed(width: 300) {
            ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
          }
        }
      }
      new_students {
        firstname
        student_img {
          childImageSharp {
            fixed(width: 30) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
const ClassName = styled.div`
  color: white;
`
const Section = styled.div`
  margin-top: 20px
`

export default function Class({ data }) {
  const { strapiClassList } = data;
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container className={`justify-content-md-center pt-5`}>
        <Row className={`justify-content-md-center`}>
          <Col className={`col-md-auto`}>
            <ClassImg
              Tag="section"
              className={`class-img`}
              fixed={strapiClassList.class_img.childImageSharp.fixed}
            >
              <ClassName className={`class-name text-center`}>{strapiClassList.classname}</ClassName>
            </ClassImg>
            <Section>
              <p>{strapiClassList.days}</p>
              <p>{strapiClassList.start} - {classdesc.end}</p>
              <p>{strapiClassList.class_desc}</p>
              <p>{strapiClassList.new_students.firstname}</p>
            </Section>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Assuming that you don't have any problems in the GraphQL query, you where restructuring wrong the data here:

```
export default function Class({ data }) {
  const classdesc = data.strapiClassList
```

You were only getting `classdesc`.

Your queried data is always inside `props.data.queryName` (change `queryName` for the correct value, `strapiClassList` in your case) so it will  stands for `props.data. strapiClassList`. Since you are destructuring `props` as `data`,  you can directly access your nested properties, your data will be inside in `strapiClassList` directly.

You can destructure again `strapiClassList` if you want to get the property name itself.

Comment: 0


I am actually going to close this issue because I copied the wrong component. In any case I am going to try your fix because they are virtually identical. Though I wasn't having any issues with this component I am hoping your fix will help.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Yes please, consider accepting/closing the issue